# Error open: command not found during command script in mac

Tags: bash, macos, command-line

I built a new script that set env and open intellij:

```
#! /bin/bash
launchctl setenv USERNAM ttt, PASSWORD 
1234
#! /bin/bash
 open -a "IntelliJ IDEA"
```

when i ran it on terminal separately it works but when i run on my script im getting this error **"open: command not found"**

i'm using mac osx

thanks

Comment: Looks like there's a control character before the work open. Remove that.

Comment: what do you mean control character? i can see that...

Comment: [This is what I mean by control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

Answer (score 1):

solution:
it was actually an extra space or end of line I made by mistake...

Comment: If it were truly a regular space it would be fine -- it would have to be a control character like a non-breaking space to cause this problem.

Comment: (and the `1234` on its own makes no sense -- if you want to handle a password prompt from `launchctl`, just putting the password on a separate line in the script doesn't do that; it tries to run the password as a separate command, it doesn't feed it as input to `launchctl`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `launchctl setenv ...` does, and how it affects your current shell, but I think your script can be more simply written:

```
#! /bin/bash
export USERNAM="ttt"
export PASSWORD="1234"
open -a "IntelliJ IDEA"
```

or

```
#! /bin/bash
env USERNAM="ttt" PASSWORD="1234" open -a "IntelliJ IDEA"
```